# How to poll AWS CLI in shell script?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

As part of my CD pipeline in snap-ci.com, I want to start the instances in my AWS opsworks stack before deploying the application.

As starting hosts takes a certain amount of time (after the command has already returned), I need to poll for the instances to be running (using the describe-instances command in AWS CLI). This command does return a full JSON response of which one of the fields contains the status of the instance (e.g. "running").

I am new to shell scripting and AWS CLI and would appreciate some pointers. I am aware that I can also use the AWS SDK's to program it in java, but that would require to deploy that program to the snap-ci hosts first which sounds complex as well.

Comment: What AWS cli tools are you using? The python ones can be used from python easily enough which should let you operate on the json result objects easily enough. You can do that with python even if you use the AWS cli tools as tools (by piping the output into python or something and then operating on the json).

Comment: I am using the AWS CLI, and shell scripts which works fine. The main issues are the behaviour of the AWS calls which should be independent of the CLI tools being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS CLI has support for [wait](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/index.html) commands, those will block and wait for the condition you specify, such as waiting for an instance to be ready.

The [Advanced Usage of the AWS CLI](http://youtu.be/vP56l7qThNs) talk from Re:Invent 2014 shows how to use waiters (18:55), queries, profiles and other tips for using CLI.

Comment: Thx. only issue is that when using the ec2 wait command to poll for running instances, the command returns even though the server isn't running yet. I also wrote the following script which throws an InvalidInstanceID at the last step. any idea ? 

aws opsworks --region us-east-1 start-stack --stack-id 9e1b0534-5b38-4fa5-b30c-f849dda8f46b          
instance_id=$(aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-instances --stack-id 9e1b0534-5b38-4fa5-b30c-f849dda8f46b --query "Instances[].Ec2InstanceId" --output text)
aws ec2 wait --region ap-southeast-1 instance-running --instance-ids $instance_id

Comment: sorry for the garbled message, adding comments to answers is not the most user friendly feature here